# kNN imputation in R but receiving error message - subscript out of bound

Tags: r, syntax-error, knn, imputation, subscript

I am quite new to programming. Below is the image of code I have written for kNN imputation using VIM package. I do not know what I am doing wrong that on running I am getting error message subscript out of bound.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbUA3.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as image. And in your code, replace `ZONE` with `Zone` since the column is named `Zone`.

Comment: replaced ZONE with Zone, still getting the same error message

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).